# when i am trying to appendchild to a div using its classname it doe'nt append the element but if i append by directly using div

Tags: javascript, html

when i am trying to appendchild to a div using its classname it doe'nt append the element but if i append element directly to the div without using the classname then its easily append it . And i already tried window.onload but it doe'nt work.

```
 // Not appending event after the use of window.onload 

let para = document.createElement('p').textContent = 'anything';
  document.querySelector('chat-box').appendChild(para);
```

Here chat-box is the name of class of div element

But works if i direcly append to it

```
let para = document.createElement('p').textContent = 'anything';
  document.querySelector('div').appendChild(para);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your initialization expression is resulting in `para` being a reference to the string `'anything'`, not the new `<p>` tag. You'll have to fix that:

```
let para = document.createElement('p');
para.textContent = 'anything';
```

Then you have to fix the selector:

```
document.querySelector('.chat-box').appendChild(para);
```

It's `.chat-box` to select by class.